# Javascript bot different triggers for responses

Tags: javascript, bots

I have created a simple javascript bot and I'm trying to figure out a way to add another trigger for a certain response without creating a new array. 
The code below is as so, before the comma ("hi",) is the trigger, and after the comma (,"hello") is what the bot is programmed to respond with. I've been trying to figure out a way to add more triggers so the bot would still respond with "hello" if the user typed "hey" instead of "hi". I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Help would be much appreciated!

```js
var convpatterns = new Array(
  new Array("Hi", "Hello."),
  new Array("How are you?", "Good. How are you?"),
```

Comment: Looks like you need a tree structure instead of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two JavaScript dictionaries, wrapped in an object, like so.

```js
function Chatter() {
  var self = this;
  self.responses = {
    0: 'hello',
    1: 'Good, how are you?',
    4096: 'Say what!?'
  };
  self.triggers = {
    'hi': self.responses[0],
    'hey': self.responses[0],
    'How are you?': self.responses[1]
  }
  self.converse = function(input) {
      if(input in self.triggers) {
          return self.triggers[input];
      }
      return self.responses[4096];
  }
}

chatter = new Chatter();
console.log(chatter.converse('hi'));
console.log(chatter.converse('asd'));
console.log(chatter.converse('hey'));
```

Dictionaries can be created with curly brackets in javascript var myDictVar = {}, keys and values can be added like shown in the example above.

Dictionary datatype in programming is like a real dictionary, it's optimized for quickly looking up a value by a key.